# Why does writing to stdout in a hot loop cause an out of memory shutdown?

Tags: node.js, operating-system, out-of-memory, stdout

```
for (i = 0; i < 3e11; i++) {
   process.stdout.write('aaaabbbbccccdddd') 
   process.stdout.write('\n') 
}
```

Or this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3e11; i++) {
   console.log('aaaabbbbccccdddd') 
}
```

Just run in a terminal like this: `node test.js`

After about one minute produces this:

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: semi-space copy, fallback in old gen Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Where does it eat memory?

```
$ node -v
v6.1.0
```

Comment: If a process is writing to stdout, but nobody is listening, does it actually take up memory? In other words: what context is this code being run in?

Comment: @CodeCaster this is just run in a terminal.

Comment: Works fine for me (for 15 seconds and counting).

Comment: what's your node version?

Comment: @djechlin, I should have been more specific, it takes about a minute.

Comment: Yeah I crash too. I think this is a somewhat OS-level question, probably the output goes to buffer and stays in buffer faster than it's written to terminal until OOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's covered in this bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1741

It's considered an open bug in node.js. It seems to have to do with an asynchronous property of `stdout` and can be fixed with:

```
process.stdout._handle.setBlocking(true);
```

I'm honestly confused since I understood `console.log` was blocking. The issue may be more subtle than "blocking" v. "not blocking," I imagine it's blockingly writing to a buffer that's nonblockingly writing to out, but not sure. (Consider this answer to be incomplete.)

Comment: Just curious, how did you find it specifically?

Comment: @exebook one, I made your question title more specific. two, once I realized it was a more specific question, I just googled the question title. Which is why it pays to ask good, specific questions :P